# My Wordpress Change File Permissions Automatically After 2 or 3 days

Tags: wordpress, function, post

I have install wordpress betheme nulled, it's changing my file permissions after 2 or 3 day automatically.

1. post.php in wp-includes - change permission 0644 to 0000
2. functions.php in wp-content/themes/betheme/ - change permission 0644 to 0000

Guide me, how can i resolve this issue with Wordpress.

I have tried some(BeTheme Header Builder and WPBakery Page Builder) of my website plugins delete & deactivate (both). Installed plugins are: 1. BeTheme Header Builder, 2. Contact Form 7, 3. Duplicate Post, 4. Force Regenerate Thumbnails, 5. Slider Revolution and 6. WPBakery Page Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using nulled theme can be vulnerable and in many cases can create a backdoor to attackers. Try to use officially provided themes and plugins for your site and check it again if the issue has been solved or not. If it has been solved then the nulled theme was the culprit causing the issue.

Comment: Garvit, i found that when i have update my recent wordpress version to latest version this is happen in every installed wordpress while some of my wordpress themes are licensed. why this is happening, especially on new wordpress version.

Comment: Is your WordPress site still working? Try to install a security plugin if you haven't installed one. While WordPress needs some specific file permissions to work [Read Here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/)  WordPress updates don't change the file permission automatically. Sometimes it is caused by a security plugin and sometimes it is caused by the host or vulnerable plugins or themes.

Comment: Garvit, yes my websites are working but i need to change permission every 2nd day and i don't have installed any security plugin, let me try this, then what happen next i told you. Thanks